# Query to find most number of rows with greatest sum

Tags: sql, oracle, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

I have a table that is like below, as example

```
A.    1
B.    2
C.    3
D.    99
E.    90
```

I need a query that calculates and returns the set of the greatest number of rows that sum to equal or less than 102, for example, choosing the set with the total nearest to the target.

If there are tied results that have the same total and same number of rows then take the set with the highest single value of Accessible

In this example the answer is `A,B,D` because that has three items, while `C,D` (which also sums to 102) only has two.

Comment: This question is very hard to understand, you need to clarify your logic for getting the desired output. For instance, why isn’t c,d the answer? Maybe you shouldn’t put your whole explanation of the logic into one sentence

Comment: Given that this is a Knapsack Problem question you will find [this blog piece by Brendan P](http://aprogrammerwrites.eu/?p=560#.W_paKJP7QWo) very useful.

Comment: Then describe that in your question, my main point isn’t if c,d or a,b,d is the best solution. My point is that your question is hard to understand.

Comment: Maybe you can improve your question by showing what you have tried yourself?

Comment: I haven't the time to write out the code, but my way would be to iteratively find the largest number <= the target, subtract that from the target then repeat until the target is 0.

Comment: I couldn't resist. See my untested attempt below as an idea for one way you ight do this.

Comment: @APC Sorry about that but as I said the content of your comment wasn't what I was after.

Comment: *"value of Accessible"*: what is that?

Comment: How many records you have in reality?

Comment: @trincot  about 50 records

Comment: @r.malekmohammadi . . . What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive query, but as this is a non-polynomial problem, the performance will degrade with more records. The first `with` query is just generating the sample data. In your case you would of course query your actual table:

```
with tbl(key, value) as (
    select 'A',  1 from dual union all
    select 'B',  2 from dual union all
    select 'C',  3 from dual union all
    select 'D', 99 from dual union all
    select 'E', 90 from dual
),
rec(greatest_key, greatest_single, key_count, keys, total) as (
    select     key,
               value,
               1,
               key, 
               value
    from       tbl
    union all
    select     tbl.key,
               greatest(tbl.value, rec.greatest_single),
               rec.key_count+1,
               substr(rec.keys, 0, 1000) || ', ' || tbl.key,
               rec.total + tbl.value
    from       rec 
    inner join tbl 
            on tbl.key > rec.greatest_key
           and rec.total + tbl.value <= 102
),
ordered(total, keys, r) as (
    select   total, keys, row_number() over ( 
                          order by total desc, key_count desc, greatest_single desc)
    from     rec
)
select total, keys
from   ordered
where  r = 1
```

The `ordered` part is only there to get the "top" record.

See it run on [rextester](https://rextester.com/NAYK34706).

If you have Oracle 12c+ you can end the query without using `ordered`:

```
select   total, keys
from     rec
order by total desc, 
         key_count desc
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Any feed-back?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. **NOT TESTED.**

```
FUNCTION find_min_set ( p_target IN NUMBER ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  CURSOR c1 ( p_find_val NUMBER ) IS
    SELECT the_id, the_val
    FROM   the_table t1
    WHERE  the_val = ( SELECT MAX( the_val ) the_val
                       FROM   the_table
                       WHERE  the_val <= p_find_val ) ;
  l_target NUMBER;
  l_id     VARCHAR2(16);
  l_val    NUMBER;
  l_ret_List  VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
BEGIN
   l_target := p_target;
   WHILE l_target > 0 LOOP
      OPEN c1 ( l_target );
      FETCH c1 INTO l_id, l_val;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      CLOSE c1;
      l_ret_list := l_ret_list || ' ' || l_id;
      l_target := l_target - l_val;
   END LOOP;
   l_ret_list := 'Target: ' || p_target || ',' ||
                  'Remaidner: ' || l_target ||  ', ' ||
                  'List: ' || l_ret_list;
   RETURN ( l_ret_list );
END;
/
```

The query returns the col with the largest value <= the target.
The returned value is subtracted from the target and we serach again for teh largest value <= the new target.
We repeat this until the new target is 0 (original tager has been reached) or theer are no more values <= target.
Form teh results as required and return.

Comment: Starting with the largest single value will produce a suboptimal answer. For instance, give the OP's example it will alight on `D, C` rather that `D, B, A`. Given that this is a knapsack problem, it can only be adequately solved with a recursive/combinatorial approach.